# Text to Math equation in Python

Tags: python, text-recognition

I'm writing now a pet project in which I want to draw a plot in the terminal window. The idea is that user print an equation, like `x = y + 1`, or `3 * x = y`. The question is how can I transfer this string equation to an equation in Python.

For instance:
I have an array, for `x` values like:

```
x_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And then I want to put it into the user's equation to get `y` values. or vise versa (vise versa, put `y` values to get `x` values)

Thought to create a lot of if conditions and use for loop to detect every character but it seems something like a sandbox. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You want to draw equations using  ∫ or √ or ∑ in a terminal, i.e. in text format? Or you want to plot a graph in a terminal using ASCII art?

Comment: Take a look on [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

Comment: You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). While it will evaluate all kinds of inputs beyond math equations, that doesn't really matter if this code is only ran at the users' platforms.

Comment: To me it seems that you have multiple problems at once and you should tackle each one individually.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, yes, I want to plot graph in a terminal usin ASCII art. I understand that  there will be more problems with complex equations, by I do it step by step. Now I want just to print points on a plot which are in the equation

Comment: @a_guest seems interesting, thnks! Will try it!

Comment: You can also take a look at [the plotext project](https://github.com/piccolomo/plotext) for inspiration.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thks! Will watch it too

Comment: @a_guest, yea, saw it. Quite interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eval for evaluating the textual commands.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using sympy library.

```
      from sympy import *
      from sympy.solvers import solve
      x,y = symbols('x,y')
      eq = '3*x=y*2'
      parts = [x.strip() for x in eq.split('=')]
      final_eq = parts[1]+'-({})'.format(parts[0])
      equation = Eq(eval(parts[0]),eval(parts[1]))
      x_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
      for x1 in x_array:
            print('given x={}, y={}'.format(x1,solve(equation.subs(x,x1),y)))
```

Ouput

```
      given x=1, y=[3/2]
      given x=2, y=[3]
      given x=3, y=[9/2]
      given x=4, y=[6]
      given x=5, y=[15/2]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more easy with: 
`equation = "x = y + 1"`  
`x_arr = []`  
`y_arr = [1,2,3]`  
`x_part, y_part = equation.lower().replace(" ", "").split("=")`  
`for i in y_arr:`  
    `y = i`  
    `x_arr.append(eval(y_part))`  
`print(x_arr)`

Comment: This would be a hard coded solution  for a particular type of equations (like x=m*y+c). Won't work for eqs like 3*x=y or 2+x=y+5